# Codeigniter - Img value with JSON format

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I use "Insert Function" in Controller for Add new Service Page. It works successfully. So I use this code again with "Update Function" service by changing this code some. It works successfully too.
   When I added new service, I used JSON format for Images in SQL table. I have a problem with this: In my edit page, I have to edit 5 photos. But I can't send any data with JSON again in Edit Page in static img value. I just change something without image edit, and I send my data to my table successfully, but no Img JSON Format again if I didn't edit added Image again.

My view of Input:

```
<?php
  for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++)
  {
    $get->serviceImg = json_decode($get->serviceImg);
    foreach ($features

    as $key => $feature)
    {
      if (in_array($feature->serviceImgId, $get->serviceImg))
    {
?>

<input type="file" class="default" name="<?= 'service_' . $i ?>" value="<?php echo base_url() . 'upload/services/' . $feature->serviceImgId; ?>" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/png" />
```

My Controller update:

```
public function update($serviceId){

        $maxDim = 100;
        $uploaded_images = array();

        for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i++){
            if(isset($_FILES['service_'.$i]['tmp_name'])  &&  $_FILES['service_'.$i]['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK ) {

                $file_name = $_FILES['service_' . $i]['tmp_name'];

                list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($file_name);

                if ($width > $maxDim || $height > $maxDim) {

                    $target_filename = $file_name;

                    $ratio = $width / $height;

                    if ($ratio > 1) {

                        $new_width = $maxDim;

                        $new_height = $maxDim / $ratio;

                    } else {

                        $new_width = $maxDim * $ratio;

                        $new_height = $maxDim;

                    }

                    $src = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($file_name));

                    $dst = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);

                    imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

                    imagedestroy($src);

                    imagepng($dst, $target_filename); // adjust format as needed

                    imagedestroy($dst);

                }

                $newFilePath = APPPATH . '../upload/services/' .$_FILES['service_' . $i]['name'];

                if(move_uploaded_file($file_name, $newFilePath)) {

                    $uploaded_images[] = $_FILES['service_' . $i]['name']; // this is the target file
                }
            }
        }
        $db_data_img = array();

        foreach ($uploaded_images as  $key=>$img) {
            $img_info = array(
                'serviceImgName' => $img
            );

            $this->db->insert('serviceImg',$img_info);
            $db_data_img[] = $this->db->insert_id();
        }


        $data = array (

            "serviceEditUser" => $this->input->post("serviceCreateUser"),

            "serviceNameEn" => $this->input->post("serviceNameEn"),

            "serviceCat" => $this->input->post("serviceCat"),

            "serviceImg" => json_encode($db_data_img),

            "serviceDescEn" => $this->input->post("serviceDescEn"),

            "servicePack" => $this->input->post("servicePack"),

            "servicePrice" => $this->input->post("servicePrice"),

            "serviceType" => $this->input->post("serviceType"),

            "serviceStatus" => $this->input->post("serviceStatus"),

            "serviceEditDate" => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        );

        $update = $this->db->where("serviceId", $serviceId)->update("service", $data);

        if($update) {

            redirect(base_url("services"));

        }else {

            echo "Hata!";

        }

    }
```

Summary:
How I can send static photo value again with JSON to SQL ?

Comment: you can send image in string based on ```Base64```.

Comment: How can I do that?